# How is those cases trivial in packing L's in Tans

Tags: packing-problem

In packing problem "L's in Tans" as presented on https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/Lintan/ . I don't understand how is some cases trivial and others are not. For example case $n=4$ isn't trivial but $n=8$ is trivial.

Can someone give me prove or directions how to prove trivial cases?

Comment: You may want to ask the author how he classifies these.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I sent mail but didn't get answer

Comment: One thing common to all solutions labelled "trivial" (but also the $n=4$ solution) is that the L's forma a "pixelated" (or quantisized) version of the tan - up to possibly one missing pixel. Perhaps it is not hard to show that in such a case the tan is minimal? But again, that would make $n=4$ trivial - but perhaps this trivial solution was unknown for a long time

Comment: Oh, wait! These are only the smallest *known* tans; so I woould tend to call a solution *trivial* if it consists of a "pixelation" as just described.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think that too, asked question just to see if someone have different opinion